# c#: Unable to use RedirectStandardOutput correctly for windows Process

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I am currently copying directories recursively with a call to *xcopy* passing through the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

This was working well, until I **tried to redirect the standard output** via the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` parameter. it didn't print anything in the console **and caused the copy to fail.**

Why is this parameter `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` alone, enough to make the command fail when set to *true*?

Is it because it redirects ALL outputs like file descriptors too ?

I don't really understand the problem. Here is my code:

```
public string ExecuteCommandSync(WinProcParams parameters)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;
        Console.WriteLine("[PROC][EXEC] " + parameters.executable + " : " + parameters.command);

        // If it's a call to cmd, /c tells cmd that we want this to be executed and then exit
        if (parameters.executable == "cmd")
            procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(parameters.executable, "/c " + parameters.command);
        else
            procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(parameters.executable, parameters.command);
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false; //true
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        if (!proc.Start())
            Console.WriteLine("[PROC][ERROR] Command failed to launch!");
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine("[PROC][STDOUT] " + result);

        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        return objException.ToString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

When `RedirectStandardOutput` is set to `true`, it prints the "[PROC][STDOUT] " line. In the other case, it doesn't.

This is the output when set to *true*:

```
[PROC][EXEC] cmd : %windir%\system32\xcopy.exe "C:\Users\Quentin\Documents\Toto" "C:\Users\Quentin\Documents\Toto_7-9-2014_16-58-17" /H /J /E /C /R /I /K /Y
Le thread '<Sans nom>' (0x1acc) s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).
[PROC][STDOUT]
```

Comment: Is your `catch` clause getting hit? does any exception occur?

Comment: It occurs when `RedirectStandardOutput` is set to `false`.